# Flip Characters in a String to reach Alphabetical Order

Tags: java, string, algorithm, character

I am trying to solve a problem in which I am trying to flip characters in a string to reach alphabetical order.

In said problem I have a string of up to 6 characters and the characters can be any letter A-F.

I can perform two actions on the string

1. Flipping a character

It will flip around the the character itself and any characters following it in the string. It will also change the case of the characters, from uppercase to lowercase or vise versa.

2. Flip the whole string

The stirng is reversed and all characters change case

**The goal is to flip the characters in such a way that it will end with all of the characters in alphabetical order and the all of the characters are uppercase.**

For example, say I have `string s = 'abc'`. If I perform action 1; flip `'b'` then the string would become `s = 'aCB'`. Then, by performing action 2; I could flip the entire string by flipping `'a'` and it would end with `s = 'bcA'`. Flip `'c'` and it would turn into `s = 'baC'`. Flip the whole thing starting at `'b'` and it would become `s = 'cAB'`. Flip at `'a'` and it would become `s = 'cba'` and then flip the whole thing starting `'c'` and get `s = 'ABC'` which would be the final answer.

I am trying to find an algorithm that will do this optimally. The above example took 6 different turns of flipping to get the answer, which is the optimal amount of turns.

Is there an algorithm out there that can do this?

Comment: [Pancake sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting)?

Comment: @user58697 yes, reminded me of pancake sort too but this seems more involved for 2 reasons, at leas. It also flips the case of the letter and it reverses the order to the end, not to the front, as in pancake sort.

Comment: @user1948 it is a version of pancake sort. I am doing the algorithm for a school assignment